# Very low Random Forest Score on Time Series Data (Multi-Classification)

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, time-series, random-forest

I'm attempting to classify seismic events which are very challenging. I have a validation accuracy of 68% using a CNN however when attempting to get a baseline for random forest I receive very poor results. Somewhere around 35%. I'm new to using Random Forest and I'm looking for some help. The shape of the data is (500,15001) 500 being the number of samples and 15001 is the numpy array amount of data points in the time series data (I.E the seismic data). Then the labels are (500,). There are 4 different types of classification from Rockfall to Earthquake.

```
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(data, data_labels_np, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 2)
num_classes = len(np.unique(yTrain))

scaler = StandardScaler()
xTrain = scaler.fit_transform(xTrain.reshape(-1, xTrain.shape[-1])).reshape(xTrain.shape)
xTest = scaler.transform(xTest.reshape(-1, xTest.shape[-1])).reshape(xTest.shape)

n_estimators = [25]
max_depth = [25]
min_samples_leaf = [2]
bootstrap = [True, False]

param_grid = {
    "n_estimators": n_estimators,
    "max_depth": max_depth,
    "min_samples_leaf": min_samples_leaf,
    "bootstrap": bootstrap,
}

rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)

rf_model = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=4, verbose=10, n_jobs=-1,error_score='raise')
rf_model.fit(xTrain, yTrain)

print("Using hyperparameters --> \n", rf_model.best_params_)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 42)

rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = param_grid, n_iter=50, cv =4, verbose = 10, random_state=42, n_jobs = 10)
rf_random.fit(xTrain, yTrain)

rf_model.best_params_
rf_model.best_score_
rf_model.best_estimator_
print('Best score for training data:', rf_random.best_score_,"\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [mcve] and update your post accordingly. Mainly we miss trial dataset to reproduce your issue. What would be the expected output of your algorithm?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is around 500 to 700 lines of code to take raw seismic data to the final Scaled data before being input into the model and so I cannot provide sample data. The expected output is a classification of 4 different types of seismic event.

Comment: No need to publish those 700 lines of code, a text export (eg. CSV) of `data` in sufficient to make your code executable by the community and investigate your problem. Have a good day.

Comment: Have you tried the shuffle=True parameter in train_test_split function? Is that valid for your use case?

Comment: If it changes the order in which they appear but retain the same labels then I could use this. Though I believed that in doing this it would change the order so the labels may be different from the seismic traces